# Spinner. Случайный вывод фраз

Tags: android, массивы, arraylist, вывод

Есть одна кнопка и Спиннер с четырьмя категориями:

```
<string-array name="categorys">
        <item>category-1</item>
        <item>category-2</item>
        <item>category-3</item>
        <item>category-4</item>
    </string-array>
```

Есть ещё четыре строковых массива:

```
<string-array name="category_1">
        <item>Фраза из первой категории-1</item>
        <item>Фраза из первой категории-2</item>
        <item>Фраза из первой категории-3</item>
        <item>Фраза из первой категории-4</item>
        <item>Фраза из первой категории-5</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="category_2">
        <item>Фраза из второй категории-1</item>
        <item>Фраза из второй категории-2</item>
        <item>Фраза из второй категории-3</item>
        <item>Фраза из второй категории-4</item>
        <item>Фраза из второй категории-5</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="category_3">
        <item>Фраза из третьей категории-1</item>
        <item>Фраза из третьей категории-2</item>
        <item>Фраза из третьей категории-3</item>
        <item>Фраза из третьей категории-4</item>
        <item>Фраза из третьей категории-5</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="category_4">
        <item>Фраза из четвёртой категории-1</item>
        <item>Фраза из четвёртой категории-2</item>
        <item>Фраза из четвёртой категории-3</item>
        <item>Фраза из четвёртой категории-4</item>
        <item>Фраза из четвёртой категории-5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Идея простая. Через спиннер выбирается категория и нажимается кнопка. Исходя из того какая категория выбрана, выводится рандомная фраза. То есть, если выбрано category-1, то выпадать фразы будут из массива category_1, category-2 -> category_2 и т.д. Думаю понятно. 
Вот так выглядит мейн класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WordsClass expert = new WordsClass();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickFindText(View view){
        TextView words = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.words);
        Spinner category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);
        String wordsType = String.valueOf(category.getSelectedItem());
        List<String> wordsList = expert.getWords(wordsType);
        StringBuilder wordsFormatted = new StringBuilder();

        for (String word : wordsList){
            wordsFormatted.append(word).append('\n');
        }
        words.setText(wordsFormatted);
    }
}
```

На всякий случай, если я где-то тут туплю. 
А вот так выглядит ещё один класс, где и нужно задать рандомизатор фраз.

```
public class WordsClass {

    List<String> getWords(String category){
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        if(category.equals("category-1")){
            words.add("Фраза из первой категории-1");
        }
        else if (category.equals("category-2")) {
            words.add("Фраза из второй категории-1");
        }
        else if (category.equals("category-3")) {
            words.add("Фраза из третьей категории-1");
        }
        else {
            words.add("Фраза из четвёртой категории-1");
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

Так выводится по одной фразе, это я уже разобрался. Так вот, нужно:
а) В зависимости от выбранной категории выводить случайную фразу, как уже говорил.
б) По возможности избавится от текста в скобках. То есть, хочется чтобы текст был в стриг файле, как положено.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, зачем из класса возвращается список, если нужна одна фраза, но можно сделать вот так (без доп классов):

```
String[][] allWords;

void someMethod() {
Resources res = getResources();
    allWords = new String[][]{res.getStringArray(R.array.category_1), res.getStringArray(R.array.category_2),
             res.getStringArray(R.array.category_3), res.getStringArray(R.array.category_4)};

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textView.setText(allWords[position][new Random().nextInt(allWords[position].length)]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
}
```

вместо `String[][]` можно использовать `List<String[]>`, в этом случае можно сделать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
        allWords.add(res.getStringArray(res.getIdentifier("category_" + String.valueOf(i+1), "array", ТекущийКонтекст.getPackageName())))
```

по аналогии - `new Random().nextInt()` можно задать и в вашем классе.